# WCF Protectionlevel, why is there no 'encryptOnly'?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, security

I'm attempting to make a client that uses WCF to communicate with a SOAP endpoint made in Java. The service requires me to send my PKCS10 request inside a encrypted SOAP request, using a X509 certificate that I have received from the service using another function, but I can't figure out how to configure WCF properly to allow me to only encrypt but not sign, seeing as I have yet to receive my final certificate from the service.

I've tried to set the X509 certificate I've received from the server as both DefaultCertificate for the service and the ClientCertificate, but no matter what kind of options I set for the binding and endpoint, I always end up with the error "The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate" and that's because (I assume) there are only the following ProtectionLevels in WCF:

- None
- Sign
- EncryptAndSign

I understand the error here because obviously I haven't received the service's private key and setting the service's certificate as the ClientCertificate I would expect this error, but is it me who has misunderstood something here?

Shouldn't it be possible for me to just encrypt the SOAP envelope using the service's public key that I've already received, without having to sign it as well with my own private key (which I haven't actually received yet)?